# Installing JDK on OSX Lion for Scala

Tags: scala, java

I just signed up for the [Coursera class on Scala](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun) and one of the requirements is Java Virtual Machine JDK 1.6 or higher.

I'm actually a PHP/Py/Ruby developer and haven't touched Java in 10 years.

What do I actually need to install on my Mac (10.7.5 Lion)?

`javac -version` gives me 1.6.0_15

is this all I need other than the Scala install, or do I need to download specific developer tools? I plan on developing Scala with SublimeText2, there's an sbt plugin for it now.

Answer (score 1):

Scala is a popular enough of a language for there to be plenty of information on how to get started from scratch. For example, googling for "scala installation" gave me (amongst other stuff) http://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/scala_environment_setup.htm —they talk about JVM versions, how to install Scala, etc; i.e. all you need. If that page won't do, I'm sure you'll find many more.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing the coursera course, you can check out the first chapter, it explains how to install scala with a comprehensive step-by-step video.
It is in the first chapter Getting started --> Tools setup for Mac OS X.
If your course hasn't started yet, you can look up it in the archive (previous sessions of the course).

Otherwise, one way to install Scala is :

1. Download Scala on http://scala-lang.org/download/
2. Extract it in your favorite folder, let's call it ~/installations/scala-X.Y.Z
3. Open the file ~/.bashrc (~/.zshrc if you are using zsh...)
4. Write :

```
export SCALA_HOME=~/installations/scala-X.Y.Z/
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
```

1. Type in your terminal :  source ~/.bashrc
2. There you go, you can now access scala by typing scala in your terminal